# ASN.1 Syntax Checker

Tags: syntax, asn.1

I'm looking for an ASN.1 Syntax Checker.

I've tried [ASNDT Eclipse Plugin](http://www.asnlab.com/asndt/overview.html), but it provokes my eclipse to crash.

I also tried to download this other one: [ASN.1 Syntax Checker](http://www.oss.com/asn1/products/asn1-syntax-checker/asn1-syntax-checker.html), but without success.

Does anyone know of a ASN.1 syntax checker available somewhere?

Comment: Please try again downloading the OSS ASN.1 Syntax Checker. The download link should work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find additional ASN.1 Tools (which are more than just syntax checkers) at the following link:  http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/asn1/links/index.htm.  An good ASN.1 compiler can also be used as a syntax checker, but please try again to download the OSS ASN.1 Syntax Checker.  It is available free of charge.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the ASN.1 extension on VS Code.
https://github.com/JonathanWilbur/vscode-asn1